What package can allow me to typeset code and pseudocode in the following way?
I'm using algorithm and algpseudocode and I get nice results but I want to have in a single environment multiple algorithms/codes in the following way:
instead of having 2 different environments, I want 1 instance with the caption "Stack realization with Array", below it I'll have piece of code #1 called "Create(S,N) function" with the code numbered lines, afterwards I want to have another code called "IsEmpty(S)" that then again will have all it's code numbered again from 1, and so on.
so it'll have a hirachcy of big label (in my case "Stack realization with Array") which will hold many pieces of code, each one with its own mini label and numbering.
how can I do that? and with what packages?

here's the code to produce this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode, caption, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{Stack realization using Array: Create(S,N) function}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State initialize an array of size N
    \State $S.top \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption*{Stack realization using Array: IsEmpty(S) function}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If{$S.\text{top} = 0$}
        \State \Return \text{true}
    \Else 
        \State \Return \text{false}
    \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


As I read your code example, one of the two packages is obsolete, i.e. not used. So what's your problem? You could abbreviate code a little by defining your own NewEnvironment ... see here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments

@MS-SPO I've listened to your advice and created a new environment, do you know if there's a simple way for me to resize it or do I have to define it when defining the environment?
and should I post this as an answer/(or edit the question) to myself this environment for people with similar requests in the future?

Sorry, I don't understand your issue, especially without any code shown. Perhaps the best way to do is a new (follow-up) question, where you show your approach and problem?

@MS-SPO, I've posted my answer, what im asking for is if you know of a quick command I can use to scale the output of this new environment, for example, I want to scale it to 70% of the original size or scale it to 12cm of height, regular scaling like this.

Right, I've seen it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721796/245790 ; much better, even with answers ;-)  May be it's a good time do delete your anwser (or ask for it) ?

do you want me to delete my question/answer here?

Only your answer, as it doesn’t fit the problem(question)/solution(answer) scheme. That’s my suggestion. Let me flag it and some veterans here will take care of it.
