Is there a way for me to scale a custom environment I made in LaTeX?
I've created the following new environments and I want to be able to scale the output of the big algorithm environment and control the width of the mini algorithm environment (or having two mini algorithm environments side by side).
Here's the setup and a working example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Define a new environment 'BigAlgorithm' with a big label
\NewEnviron{BigAlgorithm}[1]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
    title=#1,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-1mm},
    boxed title style={
      size=title,
      colback=black,
      colframe=black,
    },
    arc=5mm,
    top=2mm,
    before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
    after=\par\bigskip,
  ]
    \BODY
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

% Define a new environment 'MiniAlgorithm' with a mini label inside BigAlgorithm
\NewEnviron{MiniAlgorithm}[1]{
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{#1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \BODY
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
}

\begin{document}

% Usage Example
\begin{BigAlgorithm}{Stack realization using Array}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Create(S,N) function}
        \State initialize an array of size N
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets 0$
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{IsEmpty(S) function}
    \If{$S.\text{top} = 0$}
        \State \Return \text{true}
    \Else 
        \State \Return \text{false}
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{ Push(S,x) function}
    \If{$S.\text{top} = N$}
        \State error "overflow"
    \Else 
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets S.\text{top} +1$
        \State $S [S.\text{top}] \gets x$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Pop(S) function}
    \If{IsEmpty(S)}
        \State error "underflow"
    \Else 
        \State $res \gets S[S.\text{top}]$        \Comment{res is dummy variable}
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets S.\text{top} -1$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Top(S) function}
    \If{IsEmpty(S)}
        \State error "underflow"
    \Else 
        \State \Return $ S[S.\text{top}]$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
\end{BigAlgorithm}

\end{document}

Here's the output:


Instead of wrapping a tcolorbox in a new environment, you could directly define the new environment via \newtcbox

If you want the algos side by side, place them in minipages or use a split tcolorbox with the sidebyside layout.

Scaling text is Officially Evil. Well, typographically. If you want a larger font size, you should use the font at the relevant size and not just scale up smaller characters. Fonts with optical sizes will look different because different sizes are tweaked by the font designer e.g. smaller characters are proportionately thicker. You also (should) want consistent line widths etc. e.g. if your document uses lines of three widths, it should use the same three consistently and not arbitrary sizes in between. [But sometimes scaling is a quick-fix, albeit a dirty one or useful for special effect.]

I guess you just need multicol.
In the code below I removed all instances of \NewEnviron. It's almost never necessary when the \BODY isn't processed in some way.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Define a new environment 'BigAlgorithm' with a big label
\NewTColorBox{BigAlgorithm}{m}{
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    coltitle=white,
    fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
    title=#1,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-1mm},
    boxed title style={
      size=title,
      colback=black,
      colframe=black,
    },
    arc=5mm,
    top=2mm,
    before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
    after=\par\bigskip,
}

% Define a new environment 'MiniAlgorithm' with a mini label inside BigAlgorithm
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MiniAlgorithm}{m}{
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{#1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
}{\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

% Usage Example
\begin{BigAlgorithm}{Stack realization using Array}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Create(S,N) function}
        \State initialize an array of size N
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets 0$
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{IsEmpty(S) function}
    \If{$S.\text{top} = 0$}
        \State \Return \text{true}
    \Else 
        \State \Return \text{false}
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{ Push(S,x) function}
    \If{$S.\text{top} = N$}
        \State error "overflow"
    \Else 
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets S.\text{top} +1$
        \State $S [S.\text{top}] \gets x$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Pop(S) function}
    \If{IsEmpty(S)}
        \State error "underflow"
    \Else 
        \State $res \gets S[S.\text{top}]$        \Comment{res is dummy variable}
        \State $S.\text{top} \gets S.\text{top} -1$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
  \begin{MiniAlgorithm}{Top(S) function}
    \If{IsEmpty(S)}
        \State error "underflow"
    \Else 
        \State \Return $ S[S.\text{top}]$
    \EndIf
  \end{MiniAlgorithm}
\end{multicols}
\end{BigAlgorithm}

\end{document}


